# how to insert formfield values to database

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to insert the following in database:
image,
image name, 
price
but I have no idea to extract data from `filesystem` and pass to database

```
        String name = null;
        String value = null;

        if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
            try {
                List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
                HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<>();
                for (FileItem item : multiparts) {
                    if (!item.isFormField()) {
                        System.out.println(item.getName());
                        name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                        System.out.print(name);
                        out.print(name);
                        item.write(new File("D:/projectdatas" + File.separator + name));
                    } else {

                        String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
                        value = item.getString();

                        hmap.put(fieldName, value);
                        out.println(value);

                    }
                }
                //File uploaded successfully
                out.print("Image successfully uploaded");
                request.setAttribute("message", "File Uploaded Successfully");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                request.setAttribute("message", "File Upload Failed due to " + ex);
            }
```

Comment: do you want to store image into DB ?

Comment: no .. form fields

Answer (score 0):

**In general, storing the images into the database is not recommended since it is not efficient compared to file storage on the server. Scaling of your application will have more challenges.**

> **Best approach** is to store the Image into the file-system of your
>   server and then persist the metadata of image and other details into
>   the Database. So that you can always render efficiently with your
>   mapped details.

```
Still - if you need to store for small utility purposes then you can
store the IMAGE data in BLOB type, it is supported in most of the
databases.
```

For more understanding check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay).

Comment: image name and its price already stored in DB but I want to store one more field to DB.that two values are in the "value " variable.  how to extract the values and store ?

Comment: do you have trouble in getting the correct value for 'value' variable?

Comment: there are two values actually in "value " variable . i want to store those values into db

Comment: ok.. then split the value variable based on the regular expression (ex.:_ or space) however it is being passed from the form. Then make a jdbc connection and retrieve the respective image details row and UPDATE with these fields. Correct me if I understand your requirement or not?

Comment: public static final String INSERT_QUERY = "INSERT INTO your_table_name values (<image_name>, <image_price>, <image_metadata>)";  // insert as per your columns designed
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:1527/<db_name>";
    String uName = "root";
    String uPass = "password";

    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
         Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeUpdate(INSERT_QUERY)) {
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

Comment: you can refer example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-insert-records.htm